# Difference between calling and receiving parameter with &

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is the difference between using `&` in these two cases?

1. Calling `fun1`:

   ```
   fun1(&toproc)
   ```
2. In function definition:

   ```
   def fun1(&toblock)
     # ...
   end
   ```

Is it that when receiving a parameter with `&toblock` it is converted to a Proc
and for the other case it is converted to a block?

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, but the answers to this question answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28439734/purpose-of-ampersand-in-ruby-for-procs-and-calling-methods

Answer (score 3):

In the first case, `toproc` is a variable which contains a proc, or will be cast to a proc if not.

In the second case, we are explicitly declaring that the function takes a block argument, which we can refer to by the name `toblock`.

This article gives a pretty good explanation: http://www.skorks.com/2013/04/ruby-ampersand-parameter-demystified/